# Authentication method detail - Password in the cloud

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, definition, entra

"Password in the Cloud" - is this definition meant to be a catch-all term for any saved/stored credential (via Chrome, Bitwarden, or any other password manager).  Or does it have a more exacting definition.  [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) doesn't define which I assume that it was assumed to a catch-all.

[Entra Sign-In Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWggO.png)

Need guidance on nomenclature of terms.

Answer (score 0):

Password in the cloud would most likely refer to authenticating with Entra ID/Azure AD using just a username and password - where you store that password is entirely outside of concern for Azure, the cloud here refers to Entra ID/Azure AD. Alternatives may be appropriate if your organization has an on-premises Active Directory implementation and you wish to extend from that foundation into Azure, a high level overview is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/hybrid/connect/choose-ad-authn

Password in the cloud is most likely just Password here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/concept-authentication-methods#how-each-authentication-method-works